# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$apply' of undefined from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-authentication

I want to upload an image to firebase when I register, and I want to add an image URL when updating my member profile.

After uploading the image, when the download URL is generated, it registers the event with $ broadcast or $ emit, detects the event when updating the member profile, and tries to deliver the file URL.

If $emit or $broadcast is 'undefined' in the factory, $apply will be 'undefined' if you use $apply.

I want to know the cause and the solution.

**Factory code**

```
app.factory('imageUpload', [function($rootScope){
    return {
        exec: function(event,targetObj){

            // image file check
            .....

            return { file: file, fileCheck: true };
        },
        serv: function(event, childPath){

            // firebase file upload
            .....

            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                $rootScope.$emit('UPLOAD_EVENT_URL', downloadURL);
            });

            return downloadURL; //imageUpload.serv return
        }
    };

}]); // end imageUpload
```

**Controller code**

```
app.controller('userSignUp', ['$scope', 'dialogAlert', 'imageUpload', '$location', function($scope, dialogAlert, imageUpload, $location){

    // init code
    .....

    // signup
    $scope.signUp = function(){

        //firebase signup & user update
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password).then(function(user) {

            $scope.$on('UPLOAD_EVENT_URL', function (event, fileUrl) {
                        alert("On : "+fileUrl);
            });

            user.updateProfile({
                displayName: $scope.user.penName,
                photoURL: imgUrl
            }).then(function() {
                // member update code
                .....
            }, function(error) {
                // error msg code
                .....
            });        
        }, function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            .....
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: You are using the array notation of dependency injection, but don't define the `$rootScope`. Do it like this: `app.factory('imageUpload', ["$rootScope", function($rootScope){`

Comment: Thank you very much.
It was solved. :D

Comment: But Why isn't "$on listener" working?
$scope > $$listeners > UPLOAD_EVENT_URL exist!!